# Drawing Simple Abstract Syntax Trees with Forest, without them looking odd

Tags: forest

I'm having a problem with creating some abstract syntax trees with the Forest package. As is clear below, there is a large gap between the siblings even though there is no need for such a gap, but I can't find anything in the documentation about this issue.

[image: This is what I'm able to create in TeX]

Below you can see how I've created the current tree. I'm thinking I need to align the nodes to the left somehow, if I want to get a tree looking like my drawing in the bottom of this post.

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    before typesetting nodes={content=\texttt{#1}}
}
[<regexp>, s sep=0pt
    [(seq]
    [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
        [(atom 1)]
    ]
    [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}
        [(seq]
        [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
            [(atom 2)]
        ]
        [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}
            [(seq]
            [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
                [(atom 3)]
            ]
            [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

This is what I'm looking for, but not able to create:

[image: Drawing]

Comment: I think what you need is `calign=first`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the `for tree` option `calign=first`. I.e.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    before typesetting nodes={content=\texttt{#1},
    calign=first}
}
[<regexp>, s sep=0pt
    [(seq]
    [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
        [(atom 1)]
    ]
    [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}
        [(seq]
        [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
            [(atom 2)]
        ]
        [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}
            [(seq]
            [<regexp>, edge={draw=none}
                [(atom 3)]
            ]
            [<regexp>), edge={draw=none}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]